# Creating polygonal windows for spatial analysis in r

Tags: raster, r, spatstat, maptools

I am attempting to normalize a spatial point pattern using a population density raster in r. My problem is that the function I am trying to run is recognizing the "white space" around the raster I am using as "NA", giving me the error message: **Values of the covariate ‘Y’ were NA or undefined at 32% (19493 out of 60241) of the quadrature points. Occurred while executing: ppm.ppp(X, ~offset(log(Y)), covarariates = list(Y))**.

Is there a way to create a window or data frame that traces the outline of my raster set? It should be noted that I am a grad student with very limited experience using r.

```
    library(spatstat)
    library(maptools)
    library(raster)
    library(geostatsp)
    library(rgdal)

    X <- readShapePoints("~/Documents/Data/Cyber/US/CONTIG_US/CONUS02_FREQ")
    Y <- raster("~/Documents/Data/Cyber/US/US_POP1.tif")

    ##Set the extent

    e <- extent(-125,-67,25, 50)

    ## create a window for spatstat

    WIN <- as(e,"SpatialPoints")
    X.ppp <- as(X, "ppp") 

    ## convert raster to an im object for spatstat

    Y <- asImRaster(Y)
    Y <- eval.im((Y))

    Y <- as.im(Y)

    ## Unmark X for model:

    X<- unmark(X.ppp)


    Z <- ppm.ppp(X, ~offset(log(Y)), covarariates=list(Y))
```

The raster plot looks like this:

[image: Im trying to get rid of the black rectangle...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NA-values are present in your quadrature scheme due the way you are defining your observation window (*owin*). The ***owin*** for your events (***X***) was defined as the whole extent of the raster. Remember that any raster, by default is a structure or matrix of *NxN* rows and columns. In your example, the cells with population density had a value ranging from 0 to 41, but also there are cells with NA-values, (the empty spaces in where the oceans, Canada or Mexico would be located).

***Spatast*** can calculate irregular windows, based on the minimal extent of the events (for more detail look at *?ripras*). However, *ripras* would not extract the exact US border. The easiest fix for your problem, is to employ a polygonal defining the US border as the owin, you can use a *shapefile* and importe it similarly as you did with the point file.

```
US <- readShapePoly("USBORDER.shp")

USw <- as(US,"owin")

Xpoints <- readShapePoints("~/Documents/Data/Cyber/US/CONTIG_US/CONUS02_FREQ")

X <- as(Xpoints,"ppp")[USw]
```

Be aware that all your data must have the same *Coordinate system*, based on your extent, I am assuming your data is not projected, and you are using Cartesian coordinates, so the polygon must be in the same way.

In addition, even after using a polygonal to define the owin, you might get NA-values, this could be due the resolution of your raster and/or the scale of origin of the polygon. If this happen, you could:

1) run the model

`Z <- ppm(**X**,~PD,covariates=list(PD=Y))`

*It will give you the same warning, "values of the covariate 'PD' were NA or undefined at n%"*

2) extract the quadrature scheme from Z

`**Qz** <- quad.ppm(Z,drop=TRUE) #this step will drop points within the quadrature scheme that had NA-values`

3) run the model again, but this time, use the corrected quadrature scheme

`Z1 <- ppm(**Qz**,~PD,covariates=list(PD=Y))`